# Internalization in Django works locally, but not on server (AWS EB)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

As the title says, Django's internalization works locally (with python manage.py runserver), but not on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk.

How can I fix it?

p.s. Besides, something strange is happening: in one template among other things I translate "Save" into German as "Speichern", on the server I see only "Save" was translated, but into ... "Sichern" (it's synonymous), however, I din't use the word "Sichern" anywhere in my project (I ran *grep -rnw . -e "Sichern"* to be sure).

It means that Django picks it up from somewhere, right? It also means that the server recognizes that the request is in German.

Comment: For the save part. It may be picking the translation from the 'admin' app. Do you have different settings for local and development? Are you copying the locale dir in production?

Comment: Yes, i have different settings, they concern however only database and debug on/off. Locale directory is in git repo, besides I ssh'ed into the instance and found locale directory on server.

Comment: And what happens if you try to do the `makemessages` and `compilemessages` commands?

Comment: Now, I see what happened. I ran these commands locally. However, I had ".mo" (binary compiled translations) excluder in .gitignore. That is I didn't have them on the server. Probably, I should run compilemessages on the server keeping .gitignore untouched. Right?

Comment: According to the github example yes. .mo files should be in .gitignore https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore. But I don't see any drawback on having them included on your repository. So it is a personal decision.

Comment: Now, I've executed *makemessages*, *compilemessages* commands also on the server side. ssh'ing into instance, I've checked that .mo files are now there, but internalization still doesn't work

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: deploying at AWS EB should also restart the server. However, I even terminated the environment and built it again, still no success

Comment: Mmmm I can't think of anything else. Maybe have a read at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations so you can review you have everything right.

Comment: at the end playing with *LOCALE_PATHS* (putting there all possibilities) solved the problem. However, I still have no idea why exactly it's happenning (different behavior locally and on server). Thank you for the help!

Comment: how did you fix this? i face the same issue. this is my local path now:

LOCALE_PATHS = ( 'locale', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../../locale'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../locale'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../locale'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'), )

i asked my question here, thx.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062246/django-internationalisation-works-locally-but-not-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk