# django internationalisation works locally but not on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gettext

i tried different ways to solve this problem but all doesn't work:

trial 1:
  05_compile_the_translation:
    command: "python manage.py compilemessages"
    leader_only: true

it said i have not installed the gettext software in the server. how to do it? i logged in the elastic beanstalk instance via ssh already. but i can't find any files there?

trial 2:
added the django .mo files into the git repo and deploy all of them to the website server. with this setting in django:

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    'locale',
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../../locale'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../locale'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../locale'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

but it doesn't work as well.

any luck? thx

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found my issue and fixed it.
My issue was
for the directory name in the locale folder.
i used fr_CH and fr_FR
and it doesn't work!
u have to use
fr_Fr and fr_Ch to be the directory name!

i hope it will save some ppl a lot of time.